# Count character repeats in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a Python program and I need some way to count the number of times an X or a stretch of Xs occurs in a string. So for example if the input is `aaaXXXbbbXXXcccXdddXXXXXeXf` then the output should be 5, since there are 5 stretches of X in the string.

In Perl I would have done this as follows.

```
my $count =()= $str =~ m/X+/g;
```

I'm familiar with the `re.search` command in Python, but I'm unaware of how to count the number of results, and I'm unsure whether this is the most efficient way to approach my problem in Python.

My highest priority is readability/clarity; efficiency is secondary.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: SO helps those who help themselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My initial post was a pretty clear description (with expected input and output) of a very simple problem. Maybe I should have made it clearer that I knew how to solve the problem in Perl, but this needs to be a Python program (cleared this up subsequently). But man, you guys swooped down on this question like a pack of hungry vultures. Bhargav Rao is particularly eager to dissuade others from helping someone with "homework questions".

Comment: Seriously: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/459780

Comment: It took you all of 5 minutes to shut the question down, but an hour after I fixed it it's still on hold? Or is it still not up to your standards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
>>> s = "aaaXXXbbbXXXcccXdddXXXXXeXf"
>>> import itertools
>>> sum(e == 'X' for e, g in itertools.groupby(s))
5
```

This groups the elements in the iterable -- if no key-function is given, it just groups equal elements. Then, you just use `sum` to count the elements where the key is `'X'`.

Or how about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall("X+", s))
5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
prev = None
count = 0
for letter in string:
    if letter == 'X' and prev != 'X':
        count += 1
    prev = letter
```

Comment: Whilst I agree, for something as small as this I'd rather leave an example to learn by. Anything bigger I'd have more of an issue with.

Comment: @BhargavRao Get off your high horse. I'm a research scientist with years of experience programming Perl and C, but just learning Python.

Comment: @BhargavRao Just because it's a simple question doesn't mean it's homework.

Comment: @DanielStandage It is great that you started learning python. It is also good to hear that you are a research scientist. Python, unlike C has very good documentation support available online. Apart from that there are many tutorials also available and also very good online videos are present. It is not that I am against learners or that I'm too high flying. What I meant to say is that do utilize these online resources. You are a very old member of SO and know how it functions. If you ever get a doubt after going through any code you have written umpteen number of times, Do post the .... (1/2)

Comment: question along with the code. Even I will be most interested to learn from your questions. Your original question was not just simple, it sounded much like a HW question. Sorry if I have spoken something wrong.